# How to Handle Case When Item Does Not Exist

Tags: python, django

I have a simple for loop which iterates through all objects in a local database. For each object, I reference a `presalesEngineer` and pass that `ID` to an `API` call to retrieve a `JSON` response. However, there are records in the database for which there is no value for `presalesEngineer`. When this is the case, the empty string throws a `HttpError` when a bad `URL` is passed to the `API` call. How can I handle when `presalesEngineer` does not exist, so the `API` is not passed an empty value?

views.py

```
objects = Opportunity.objects.all()

    for object in objects:
        try:
            ps_e = object.presalesEngineer
            if ps_e:
                presales_engineers = [cwObj.get_member_by_id(ps_e) for object in objects]
            else:
                presales_engineers = 'None'
        except NameError:
            presales_engineers = 'None'
```

Comment: You can use `try`-`except` to handle those.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what exception should I use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the error is not met until the API is sent a query with a missing parameter. How can I only call the API when there is some value for `object.presalesEngineer` and `else` assign a value of `None`?

Answer (score 1):

This codeblock should try to grab the presalesEngineer of your object or return None (note that the string 'None' does not equal the pytohon object None)

```
for object in objects:
    try:
        ps_e = object.presalesEngineer
        # Do stuff with an object you know for sure will not trigger an exception
        # Something like:
        # if ps_e != '': < the object is not an empty string
        # or
        # if ps_e: < the object is not None
        # after you pass whatever checks you deem necessary, you launch your API call.
    except AttributeError:
        # You can either pass here or return a None object/Empty list
        ps_e = None
```

Possible implementation below:

```
# Empty list of whatever you are searching for
engineers = []
for my_object in objects:
    try:
        ps_e = my_object.presalesEngineer
        # This is here to avoid none values in your API call
        if ps_e:
            # Just in case your API call falls
            # It will fail silently in this try codeblock
            try:
                # Assuming cwObj is your driver/API endpoint builder
                # And that you only get one single string as response
                # And that string is not some data structure that you need to split
                my_desired_id = cwObj.get_member_by_id(ps_e)
                engineers.append(my_desired_id)
            # Using bare except statements is not a good idea
            # Use HttpError here if you don't want to pass on any exception
            except:
                pass
    except AttributeError:
        # You can either pass here or return a None object/Empty list
        pass
print engineers
```

Comment: the error is when the API is sent a query with a missing paramter...so `?conditions=id=` when `presalesEngineer` does not exist. How can I only call the API when there is some value for `object.presalesEngineer` and `else` assign a value of `None` for `presales_engineer`?

Comment: See the ammended code. Basically in your try block you only work on the path which you know returns a valid object to your property call. Do note that if your object is empty or None, you can check for that before you launch you api call in an if.

Comment: ok, I am able to handle when ps_e does not exist...but only the last vale for ps_e in the database is being queried. Do I need to use a list for ps_e? See my edit to my original question.

Comment: What does calling the `presalesEngineer` property of each of your objects return? A list? A string? A comma/space separated string of values? If it's a simple string, just launch your API call for that string and append the result to a list. If its a data structure (a list of strings, or comma/space separated strings) you need to split it into atoms, call the api on each atom and append the result to your list. Then just use the resulting list.

Comment: it returns a single id as a string such as `189`. Then the query would be `?conditions=id=189`

Comment: I added an else clause to assign a value for when an item does not exist and it works great, thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad to help.